# Where can I find that chart from Windows 8 TaskManager?

Tags: windows-8, charts, taskmanager

I'd like to implement a chart in a small system I'm writing to display sales statistics and I got pretty interested in that chart used on Windows 8 Task Manager, I'd like to know if is possible to use that control? It's WPF/WindowsForm?

[image: null]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This Charts are avaiable from the `chartv.dll` from System32 directory, but it is a normal C++ DLL which is not intended to be used from 3rd party software.